# tseries date and time in R

Tags: r

I have a time line which changes every 5 minutes from 1/6/2018 00:00 till 30/9/2018 23.55
Problem: R do not recognize it.
if I ask to print one day value, it print:

```
print(DATA_P[c(1),c(1)])
[1] 6/1/2018 0:00
35136 Levels: 6/1/2018 0:00 6/1/2018 0:05 6/1/2018 0:10  
6/1/2018 0:15 6/1/2018 0:20 ... 9/9/2018 9:55
```

I want to get tseries plots and do forecasting

how to write in tseries: start date, end date, frequency.
One day is formed with 288 ares (60/5*24)

I have mistakes like:

> invalid time series parameters specified

or

> In addition: Warning
>   message: In Ops.factor(start, end) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors
>   and others

Or how to create good,recognized date and time parameters for R?

Comment: The `print` statement is printing an object of class `factor`, not a date/time object. You should coerce to class `POSIXct` with `as.POSIXct(DATA_P[, 1], format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")`. See `help("strptime")` for date/time formats.

Comment: I do with PosiXct, but i have I problem with first time value
tm1 <-as.POSIXct("01062018 00:00:00", format = "%d%m%Y %H:%M")
tm2 <-as.POSIXct("30092018 23:55:00", format = "%d%m%Y %H:%M")
     print( tm1)    answer:
[1] "2018-06-01 EEST"
  print ( tm2)  answer  "2018-09-30 23:55:00 EEST"
Error in attr(data, "tsp") <- c(start, end, frequency) : 
  invalid time series parameters specified

Comment: Those are different formats, remove the `/` and use `"%d%m%Y %H:%M:%S"` since you now have seconds.

Comment: Also, **edit the question**, not comments, with the code you are using to create the time series.